# how to execute F9 for excel spreadseet in python?

Tags: python, excel

I'm using python to execute some external command on excel.

```
x1 = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
wb = x1.workbooks.open(filePath+fileName);
x1.run("fileName!someMacro")
results+=[(wb.ActiveSheet.Cells(4,8).Value, wb.ActiveSheet.Cells(4,16).Value)];
```

And it is working, runs the macro and I can collect the results.
I have another sheet - there in Formulas bar I have a button "Calculate Now" / <kbd>F9</kbd>
I would like to run <kbd>F9</kbd> and collect results from that sheet. But the following code doesn't seems to executes <kbd>F9</kbd> - thus I'm getting all the results with same values.

```
results = []
sheet2=wb.Sheets(5).Select
for i in range(n):
    wb.Sheets(5).Calculate
    results+=[(wb.Sheets(5).Cells(12,11).Value, wb.Sheets(5).Cells(12,10).Value];
```

How can I execute the <kbd>F9</kbd> for excel from python?

Answer (score 0):

Try `wb.Sheets(5).Calculate()` to *call* the `Calculate` method.

Without parentheses, as you had it, will only return an instance of the Calculate method and *does not call it*:

```
>>> wb.Sheets(5).Calculate
<bound method _Worksheet.Calculate of <win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 14.0 
 Object Library._Worksheet instance at 0x55458248>>
```